# Why is the original value of var_a not being displayed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, equation, solver

Based on some research on another StackExchange web site, it seems that the following program should display the original value of `var_a` based on my understanding of the calculations presented. However, function `a` does not appear to calculate the value of `a` as intended, and it is not clear to me why this is the case. How should this be fixed when trying to solve for `var_a` correctly?

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import math


def main():
    var_n = 35      # thirty-five year investment
    var_iy = .04    # four percent interest per year
    var_pv = 30000  # thirty thousand dollar investment
    var_a = 12      # compounded twelve times per year
    var_fv = round(fv(var_n, var_iy, var_pv, var_a), 2)
    print('Future Value        =', var_fv)
    var_a = a(var_n, var_iy, var_pv, var_fv)
    print('Compounded Per Year =', var_a)


fv = lambda n, iy, pv, a: pv * (iy / a + 1) ** (n * a)


def a(n, iy, pv, fv):
    b = -math.log(fv / pv) / (iy * n)
    return (iy * b) / (lambert_w(b * math.exp(b)) - b)


def lambert_w(z, tolerance=1e-8):
    a = z
    while True:
        b = math.exp(a)
        c = a * b
        d = a - (c - z) / (c + b)
        if abs(a - d) <= tolerance:
            return a
        a = d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Reference**: [How would you solve this equation for “A”?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1974500)

Comment: By "close to twelve", are you meaning like `11.95`, etc?

Comment: Yes, and the value of `-19349363.130913414` is nowhere close to `+12`, the expected answer.

Comment: Doing `d = a - (c - z) / (c - b)` gets close...

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to implement a better `lambert_w` function? One case where the functions fails after the change you made is for the call `lambdert_w(10)`.

Comment: Do try to initialize with the approximation given by wikipedia `a=log(z)-log(log(z))` to start close to the solution.

Comment: That leads to an exception of `ValueError: math domain error`.

Comment: For negative `z` it has to be `a=log(-z)-log(-log(-z))` per the same source for `z` in `[−1/e, 0)`.

Comment: I'd say LutzL is on the right track with log ... `11.999842644325232`